# ASP.NET keep removing attribute from HEAD

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have my asp.net sub-master page setup like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent">
    <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.0 strict//en" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head >
            <title></title>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </head>
        <body>
            ...
        </body>
    </html>
</asp:Content>
```

Why does ASP.NET keep removing attribute that put in HEAD?  Specifically, I am trying to make it like this:

```
<head runat="server">
```

If I do not have runat in HEAD, I receive the following error:

```
Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. <head runat="server" />).
```

And here is my master master that load the sub-master page I have above:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="HeadOffice.Site" %>
<asp:contentplaceholder id="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:contentplaceholder>
```

It turn out asp:Content is removing attribute from html, head, body.  Not just head.  Is there anyway to stop it?

Comment: Yes, but my master page have a master page, don't ask me why.

Comment: And why do you need the `head` tag to `runat="server"`?

Comment: For themeing, it give me this error if not:  Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. <head runat="server" />).

Comment: Can you please show the other Master page? It is difficult to understand what is happening unless I can see both pages.

Comment: The other master page just have a contentplaceholder that get the content from that master page:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="HeadOffice.Site" %>

<asp:contentplaceholder id="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:contentplaceholder>

Comment: Good info on the title tag from Haacked: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the work around I found was that asp:content only modify your HTML if you fire off the onSave event.  So what you do instad is make your edit, then don't save, but close the VS2010 program, and click save on.  This way, asp:content will not have a chance to modify your code.  Afterward you can re-open the project.

Answer (score 0):

your main master page looks like this?

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

if not make your main masterpage looks like this code i provide you.
add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css"/>` between `<head>` tags not in `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"/>` 
for avoid deleting this.

another option why your css can disapear each postback is situation when on your `aspx` file missing `MasterPagefile` or `AutoEventWireup` attribute 
example:

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>
```

**Edit:**
If your main `PageMaster` got `<head>` tag you can't add another one to the same page like you did in your code u should add only content by

`<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"/>` placed on your `aspx` page.

Please let me know if that help:)

Comment: No.  My main master page is just a contentplaceholder.  With html, head, body, etc all in the sub-master page that get loaded into the contentplaceholder.  And I can't change this structure.

Comment: @Yongke are you using nested masterpages? or did you create this structure for your own?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use runat=server you need to give it an ID that way the server will know how to access it

Comment: Tried it.  It remove both tag on save.